# Error in confusionMatrix.matrix(data = df_name, reference = numeric_vector_name, positive = "increase" ) : matrix must have equal dimensions

Tags: r, forecasting, confusion-matrix, non-linear-regression

I have had the error in the title of this post occur 3 times in a row now and none of the first couple of resulting similar Questions on Stack Overflow when I entered this error message into Google or Bing had answers that work for my particular situation.
The script which the following lines of code come from is in my [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/Spencermstarr/Forecasting-US-Stock-Prices) for this analytics project in the R script file called "AIT 622 Big Data Analytics Project script".

```
### Classification Forecasting Model #5: Multivariate Adaptive Regression Splines
library(earth)
library(plotmo)
library(plotrix)
marsGrid = expand.grid(.degree = 1:2, .nprune = 2:38)
set.seed(100)
marsModelR1 = train(x = data2014, y = pr_var2014, method = "earth", 
                    preProc = c("center", "scale"), tuneGrid = marsGrid)

# compare the expected classifications in 2015 to the observed classifications in 2015
marsR1Pred = predict(marsModelR1, newdata = data2015)
> dim(marsR1Pred)
[1] 4120    1
```

I am adding in the following here to show what I believe might be the source of the error message/warning.
> length(pr_var2014)
[1](https://github.com/Spencermstarr/Forecasting-US-Stock-Prices) 3808

```
marsR1_PR = postResample(pred = marsR1Pred, obs = pr_var2014)
> marsR1_PR
       RMSE    Rsquared         MAE 
         NA 1.24489e-06          NA

marsModelR1_CFM <- confusionMatrix(data = marsR1Pred, reference = pr_var2014,
                                   positive = "Increase")
> marsModelR1_CFM <- confusionMatrix(data = marsR1Pred, reference = pr_var2014,
+                                    positive = "Increase")
Error in confusionMatrix.matrix(data = marsR1Pred, reference = pr_var2014,  : 
  matrix must have equal dimensions
```

I have tried the following 2 attempted fixes already with the same result for both

```
> marsModelR1_CFM <- confusionMatrix(data = marsR1Pred, 
+                                    reference = sample(pr_var2014, length(marsR1Pred)),
+                                    positive = "Increase")
Error in confusionMatrix.matrix(data = marsR1Pred, reference = sample(pr_var2014,  : 
  matrix must have equal dimensions

> length(pr_var2014)
[1] 3808
> length(marsR1Pred)
[1] 4120
> marsModelR1_CFM <- confusionMatrix(data = marsR1Pred, 
+                                    reference = sample(pr_var2014, 4120),
+                                    positive = "Increase")
Error in confusionMatrix.matrix(data = marsR1Pred, reference = sample(pr_var2014,  : 
  matrix must have equal dimensions
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated! Also, all of these commands are in the final section of my script, Part 4 at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are working with a factor for the data argument, not e.g. `matrix`.

```
# this will fail with similar error to yours
confusionMatrix(as.matrix(iris$Species), sample(iris$Species))
# Error in confusionMatrix.matrix(as.matrix(iris$Species), sample(iris$Species)) : 
#  matrix must have equal dimensions

# this will pass as I convert the variable to be a factor variable
confusionMatrix(as.factor(as.matrix(iris$Species)), sample(iris$Species))
```

for your case:

```
marsModelR1_CFM <- confusionMatrix(data = as.factor(marsR1Pred), 
                                   reference = sample(as.factor(pr_var2014), 4120),
                                   positive = "Increase")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I realized quickly after looking over your answer and trying it and getting another error message that I was completely missing the forest for the trees here because I am running a MARS, which is a regression, so I should have just used predict() instead of trying to create a confusion matrix in the first place!